# Apply same aspect ratio to every image in table row with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a few images which have same height but different widths. They are pretty big, so I need them to be resized. The problem is placing those images on a table gives me the result I want in Firefox but not on Chrome.Here is the code:

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x1000" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x1000" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/110x1000" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x1000" alt=""></td>
      <td><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130x1000" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you run this on Firefox, you'll see that all the images have the same height, because the same aspect ratio was applied. On Chrome, this does not happen. They all get a different aspect ratio.

How do I make them look the same on both Chrome and Firefox? I can change the structure if needed(table to div, etc) or use javascript, anything that's needed.

[image: What happens on Chrome]

What happens on chrome

[image: What happens on Firefox(which I want to happen)]

What happens on Firefox (which I want to happen)

Comment: they don't have the same ratio

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a html/css only issue. If it isn't solved by the time I'm home I'll take a look.

Comment: If you set them 100%, you also have to specify the width of the td, because then it will look like this in chrome. you can give the height a fixed value, to get the desired result everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply make them inside the container and apply a fixed height:

```css
.container {
 height:200px;
}
.container img {
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x1000" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x1000" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/110x1000" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x1000" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130x1000" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and effective. +1

Comment: When I use this, if I increase the containers height, but the container it's in keep its width, the images will start to go to the bottom, like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3btecfxh/. Is it possible to add an scroll instead of letting this happen?

Comment: But that doesnt enable scrolling.

Comment: @LucasT. yes it avoid the line break, for the scroll add overflow:auto

Comment: It does not work. It only creates a vertical scrolling. The images still go to the bottom.